# Contents of spam questions not hidden in mobile view

Tags: bug, mobile-web, spam

The contents of deleted spam/rude/abusive questions 
(like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20240613/1187415) 
on Stack Overflow – visible only for >= 10K users) is hidden behind an extra link:

[image]

However, in the mobile web view, the original full content is visible:

[image]

This can be observed with mobile browsers (in my case, Mobile Safari
on an iPhone), and also by switching to the mobile view in the desktop
browser (with the <kbd>Mobile</kbd> button at the bottom of the page).

The same behavior was observed on Code Review (e.g. [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/194695/35991)), so it is not
a problem specific to Stack Overflow.

This happens only with questions, not with answers: The contents
of deleted spam answers  is hidden in both the “full site” view and
the “mobile” view.

*Summary:*

```
               |   full view     mobile view
---------------------------------------------
spam question  |    hidden        VISIBLE
spam answer    |    hidden        hidden
```

I would expect the contents of spam questions in the mobile view
to be hidden as well.

Comment: @NobodyNada: You are right. For some reason, I did not find that one.